# Curl Install in PHP 7.2 but not working in application

Tags: php, curl, centos, digital-ocean, php-curl

I need small help.

I have setup centos 8 on digitalocean server and install PHP 7.2 and PHP CURL.

I can see curl in `phpinfo()`
[image]

When i call below code in my local and other server working fine.

But when i run code newly setup centos 8 on digitalocean server i get status code **0** and also i did not get any curl_error in my log or in output.

I have also manage firewall setting for this but same output i get.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$html_brand = "www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => fopen('php://stderr', 'w')
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
print curl_error($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
    .curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**CURL PRINT OUTPU**

```
[root@CookIn ~]# php -i | grep "curl"
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using Apache, or CLI, to access your script? How are you running this PHP script?
2. Remember that enabling curl in Apache is not the same as enabling it in CLI. php -i | grep "curl" should indicate if it's enabled on the CLI or not.
3. Check for more than one PHP install.

Comment: @johanFF yes i can see when i print 

[root@CookIn ~]# php -i | grep "curl"
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
curl